# How can a char and a char* be appended to an existing string?

Tags: c++, char, string-concatenation

After initializing a string, can a char and a char* be added to it in the same line:

```
char mod;//this comes in as a parameter
string line = "text";
line += mod;
line += "more text";
```

Is there a more efficient and/or possibly one-line way to do it? Something like

```
string line = "text" + mod + "more text";
```

Comment: Why do you think a one-liner is more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your one-liner won't work because `char *`s are not strings, so you can't use `+` to concatenate them with `char`s; you just end up with a pointer add.  If you want a one-liner, you could use

```
string line = string("text") + mod + "more text";
```

but that won't be any more efficient than your 3 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can do your first snippet (you would have found that just by compiling!), but not your second.

You could also consider using a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "text" << mod << "more text";
```

Comment: Sure, this is the most generic way to operate. This way you can "inject" any kind of object. Not only chars and strings but also numbers of any format, etc. Use std::stringstream !

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make sure the first operand of `+` is a `std::string`:

```
string line = string("text") + mod + "more text";
```

Then the result of `string("text") + mod` is a `std::string` and can have `"more text"` appended to it too.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `+=` returns a non-const reference, so you *can* stack `+=`. It's a bit awkward and unusual, and looks like this:

```
string line = "text";
(line += mod) += "more text";
```